# configureCell method does not work in a Custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented an UITableView with some custom cells for validate UITextFields and date pickers. I want to do an easy task but I do not why it does not work. I just want to change a UILabel text property.
I have this code to call the cell in cellForRowAtIndex...

```
   birthDateCell = (WPBirthDatePickerCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:BirthDateCellIdentifier];

        if(birthDateCell == nil){
            // INIT REUSABLE CELL
            birthDateCell = [[WPBirthDatePickerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:BirthDateCellIdentifier] ;
            [birthDateCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            // countryCell. = self;
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 5 ){
            [birthDateCell configureCellWithString:fechaNacimiento];
            return birthDateCell;
        }
```

and my custom cell;

```
@implementation WPBirthDatePickerCell
@synthesize birthDateLbl, validateLbl;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        validateLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 80, 30)];
        validateLbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        validateLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        validateLbl.text = @"Birth Day ";
        [validateLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [self addSubview:validateLbl];


        birthDateLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 200, 30)];
        birthDateLbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        birthDateLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        [birthDateLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [self addSubview:birthDateLbl];
        [self configureCellWithString:@"Whate ever"];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) configureCellWithString:(NSString *)birthDate
{
    birthDateLbl.text =  birthDate;
    NSLog(@"%@", birthDateLbl.text);
}
```

I call  `configureCellWithString` method when the user choose the right date in the `datePicker`

It is very strange  because I make a NSLog of the UIlabel text property it works, it shows me the right text in the output, but not in the real Cell. Any idea ? Thank you, is this a problem of reusability?

Comment: Does it show your initial "whatever" string?

Comment: it shows it if I do not call the method in cellForRowAtIndex, but it is obviously because until I do not take a date from the datePicker `fechaNacimiento`it is still empty. I also call configureCellWithString when I close the date picker and there it is when I get the NSLog with good data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this in a comment, but I can't comment yet.  Make sure you reload the table data after changing the cell info.

Comment: This is weird, because I do the same without reloading in other cells like Country. when I press country cell a new TableViewController is opened with a list of countries if the user press one the controller goes back and show the name in the label, all of this work without reloading. But yeah, you are right, and if I add [tableView reloadData] it works.. Thank you

Comment: Actually, now I am trying to change the color of the label if is not correct, and the same is happening. Even with reload data color is not changing..